# office 365 visio web access hyperlinks not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-integration, office

I have a office 365 account. When I open the visio.vsdx file using the Visio web Access web part. The hyperlinks do not work.  The hyperlink links to another page in the same visio file.

I have **not checked the disable the hyperlink link** in the web part properties.